# Windows, Python, VENV, and Sublime Text Build systems: Path Error When Activating VENV

Tags: python, windows, python-venv, sublimetext4

Okay, I've looked through a bunch of python venv with sublime text questions, and I'm pretty sure this issue is due to the specifics of venv on windows.

I'm on Windows, using Python 3.10, and the virtualenv package to manage my virtual environments.

I'm trying to set up a custom build in a Sublime project file that does the following:

- activate the venv for the local project
- echos the VIRTUAL_ENV to the shell to show the correct venv has been activated

I've been having issues with getting both into one build command, so here's the current array with the two steps as seperate builds:

```
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "name": "activate",
            "cmd": "$project_path/venv/Scripts/activate.bat",
            "shell": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Current VENV?",
            "cmd": "echo %VIRTUAL_ENV%",
            "shell": true
        },
    ]
```

Currently, when I run the *activate* build, I get the following:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
[Finished in 80ms with exit code 1]
[cmd: C:\Users\kreeh\Repos\project/venv/Scripts/activate.bat]
[dir: C:\Users\kreeh\Repos\project]
```

If I run `C:\Users\kreeh\Repos\project/venv/Scripts/activate.bat` in a separate cmd.exe window, it correctly activates the venv, and when I print the %VIRTUAL_ENV% var, it correctly returns the venv location.

```
C:\Users\kreeh>C:\Users\kreeh\Repos\project/venv/Scripts/activate.bat

(venv) C:\Users\kreeh>echo %VIRTUAL_ENV%
C:\Users\kreeh\Repos\project\venv
```

I assume this is an issue with how the Sublime Text build system is handling the windows path formatting. If I try and utilize the working directory param, it doesn't work, because the cmd.exe doesn't do relative paths nicely.

```
        {
            "name": "activate",
            "cmd": "venv/Scripts/activate.bat",
            "working_dir": "${project_path}",
            "shell": true
        },
```

returns

> 'venv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> [Finished in 60ms]

So, is there a way to have the Sublime Build system handle the windows path correctly, or is there a way to use a relative path in the cmd?

Comment: Even if you were to get this to work, activating a virtualenv via Sublime build system won't really *do* anything. It'll open a process, run the activate script, then close the process, without leaving any changes behind. Instead of going about things this way, just create a Python build system pointing to the virtual environment's `python.exe`, adjust `PYTHONPATH` if you wish, and away you go.

Comment: @MattDMo ahhhh okay-- so I might be making this more complicated than I need to be. It sounds like the simpler way would be to just set up custom builds for building a file, running a test, updating the installed packages using the python intepreter from the venv folder?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MattDMo pointed out the flaw in my logic, which is that the venv activation doesn't actually do anything in and of itself -- it changes the python interpreter used for future commands in that prompt window. As such, it's kind of a useless thing for a build system. Instead, I added a venv-specific pip install and build commands so far.

```
{
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "name": "pip install",
            "cmd": "${project_path}/venv/Scripts/pip3.exe install -r requirements.txt ",
            "working_dir": "${project_path}",
            "shell": true
        },
        {
            "name": "VENV Build",
            "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
            "selector": "source.python",
            "cmd": "${project_path}/venv/Scripts/python.exe $file",
            "shell": true,
        },

    ],
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
```

One thing to note, as a Windows user, I had to add the `follow_symlinks=true` to the folders list -- this is because the way venv works on windows (or at least on MY install), there's not an actual python.exe in that venv folder, it's a symlink.